# Inline edit of django ForeignKey and proxy models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-suit

I get an 404 error when I try to edit inline (in a popup) an object referenced by a ForeignKey to a [proxy model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) in the admin part (using django suite) of my application.

My base model and the proxy model:

```
class Book(MyBase):
    """
    Base book model
    """
    # [...]

class SpecialBook(Book):
    """ 
    Need to leave this separated as a proxy model.
    """
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

My model to bind books with it's genre. The `book` field can hold references to both `Book` and `SpecialBook`, via documentation:

> [proxy] class operates on the same database table as it's parent

```
class BookGenre(MyBase):
    """
    bind books with it's genre
    """

    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre)
```

The `admin.py` stuff to manage the genres:

```
class BookGenreInline(suit.admin.SortableTabularInline):
    model = BookGenre

    # [...]


@admin.register(Genre)
class GenreAdmin(AdminBase):
    inlines = [
        BookGenreInline,
        # [...],
    ]
    fields = [...]
```

The above generates me an admin page with a select field with the existing `Book` (and `SpecialBook`) objects. On the right to the select I've got the "Change selected" and "Add another" buttons (template imported from [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/related_widget_wrapper.html) I believe). The only problem is that the edit option works only when a Book object is selected, doesn't work for SpecialBook. As far as I can see it's connected with the fact that the `change_related_template_url` found [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/related_widget_wrapper.html#L7) isn't updated. The url for editing `Book` objects looks like `/admin/books/book/ID[...]` and works correctly, but doesn't change to `/admin/books/specialbook/ID[...]` when I select the `SpecialBook` object.

Can anybody suggest an elegant fix here?

Comment: what on earth is foo?

Comment: @e4c5 Sorry for that one. Just base class for admin model, nothing important in this case.